# Delete Blank Row in excel worksheet

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel

I Tried to delete blank rows from excel using the code

```
Dim wb As New Workbook("d:\test\book1.xls")
Dim sheets As WorksheetCollection = wb.Worksheets
Dim sheet As Worksheet = sheets(0)
sheet.Cells.DeleteBlankRows()
wb.Save("d:\test\mybook.xls")
```

But i am getting syntax error.Any one know the Namespace requiered to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ApplicationClass excel = new ApplicationClass();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range cellToBeDeleted = (Range)excel.Cells[rowIndex, columnIndex];
cellToBeDeleted.Delete();
```

Include the following namespace

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

Comment: i need to remove all empty rows.if any cell in a row having value,then i need to retain the row

Answer (score 0):

Try This
-Add Reference (from COM section ) Micsrosoft Excel Object Library to your project

```
  Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    delBlankRows("d:\test\book1.xls", 1)
End Sub

Private Sub delBlankRows(ByVal excelFileName As String, sheetIndex As Integer)
    Dim excel As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Dim fileName = excelFileName
    Dim w As Workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(fileName)
    Dim r As Range = w.Worksheets(sheetIndex).UsedRange.EntireRow.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeBlanks)
    r.Delete()

    w.Save()
    w.Close()
End Sub

End Class
```